# NSMutableArray initialization methods

Tags: objective-c

Is there a difference between [NSMutableArray array] and [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` returns a mutable array that you own (and therefore have to explicitly relinquish ownership using `release` when you no longer need it) and `[NSMutableArray array]` returns a mutable array that you don't own.

According to the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), any method with the word `alloc`, `new`, or `create` in the name, implies that you own the object returned from that method.